# Number values include comma -- how do I make these numeric?

Tags: r, numeric

I have a whole column of numbers that include comma separators at the thousands. When I try to create a numeric column out of them, anything over 999 becomes NA.

I used cbind:

```
df <- cbind(df, var2 = as.numeric(as.character(df$var1)))
```

and wound up with:

```
        var1  var2
1   2,518.50    NA
2   2,518.50    NA
3   5,018.50    NA
4   4,018.50    NA
5  10,018.50    NA
6     318.50 318.5
7   2,518.50    NA
8   3,518.50    NA
9   7,518.50    NA
10  1,018.50    NA
```

Is there a way to strip the commas or tell `as.numeric` how to handle them?

Comment: you can use `gsub`.  `gsub(',', '', var2)`

Comment: @mnel I think that would do something different?  Wouldn't that treat `1,000` the same as `1`?  Whereas Amanda is saying that `1,000` should be treated like `1000`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta sorry ... copy/paste error. j should be df.

Comment: @Justin, that works actually. I was too focused on telling as.numeric about formats to expect.

Comment: @Amanda, how did you get the original data into R? You may also want to google `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: parse_number() from the readr package does this well. It ignores the commas inside an number.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are trying to add a new column `var2` to `df`, you can use the following

```
  df$var2 <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", as.character(df$var1)))
```

Comment: Nice. I don't even need cbind?

Comment: nope, with data frames you can just assign.  `df[[var2]] <- value` and `df$var2 <- value` both work.

Answer (score 5):

Use `as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$var1))`.

You want to use `gsub` as `sub` will only replace the first comma.