# Replace strings in R column

Tags: r, string, replace, rename

I have a dataframe which includes the factor column "Year".

The observations in "Year" looks like this:

```
 y1995 
 y1995
 y1997
 y1997
 y1999
 y2007
 y1995
```

etc

I want to eventually convert "Year" into class integer. First, however, I need to drop the "y" from each observations, so that the data takes the form:

```
 1995 
 1995
 1997
 1997
 1999
 2007
 1995
```

etc

The years are all in the interval y1995-y2007.

How would I do this?

Comment: I'm struggling if to close this a dupe of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594223/number-values-include-comma-how-do-i-make-these-numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has a simple solution:

```
temp <- sub("y", "", df$Year)
```

and if you'd like to replace the old vector:

```
df$Year <- sub("y", "", df$Year)
```

and afterwards if you'd like to convert that column into numeric (it will still hold string, although you won't be able to see it right away):

```
df$Year <- sub("y", "", df$Year)
df$Year <- as.numeric(df$Year)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `sub` to remove the first non-numeric element.

```
df1$Year <- as.numeric(sub('y', '', df1$Year, fixed=TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Year=paste0('y', c(1995, 1995, 1997, 1997, 1999, 2007,
           1995)))
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Based on the example showed, `y` is the `prefix`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use function `str_replace` in package `stringr`.

`Year <- str_replace(Year, "y", "")`