# How to add factor (integers) in R?

Tags: r, sum, numeric

I am working with CSV file format data in R. There are 315 rows in a column called itemsDispensed. I want to calculate the total sum of these numbers.

I have tried to do sum(as.numeric(as.character(....))) in R however the result I get is different from the sum that I have got while doing in excel.

The code below shows the first 20 rows:

```
 head(select2014Chap6Sec1[ ,4], n = 20)
 [1] 11.615  0.001   0.023   0.026   56.101  7.127   8.572   0.004   0.001    45.98   225.525 0.526  
 [13] 119.999 0.004   0.522   4.781   31.473  0.001   2.338   0.712  
 6999 Levels: 0 0.001 0.002 0.003 0.004 0.005 0.006 0.007 0.008 0.009 0.01 0.011      0.012 0.013 ... 999.958
```

The method I am using shows below:

```
> sum(select2014Chap6Sec1[ ,4])
  [1] 778211
```

The error for sum(as.numeric(as.character(....))) shows below with NA value:

```
> sum(as.numeric(as.character(testFactorCol4)))
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

I can provide all the data if you want using dput method. 
Thank you

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning.  Try `sum(..., na.rm = TRUE)`.  See `?sum`  But you should really use `x <- select2014Chap6Sec1[4]; sum(as.numeric(levels(x))[x], na.rm = TRUE)` to convert numeric factors to their real numeric values

Comment: @RichardScriven, I am sorry to tell that it is not giving me the correct answer and it is still giving me the warning. I tried, x <- select2014Chap6Sec1[ , 4]; sum(as.numeric(levels(x))[x], na.rm = TRUE) 
x. The variable x has value Factor w/ 6999 levels '0'...

Comment: try `as.numeric(as.factor(x))` inside your function `sum`.

Comment: How did you get 6999 levels with only 350 rows?  For the long run, it might make sense to try to figure out why the column is being read as characters/factors in the first place.  For example, if it was because of missing value encoding then you could likely fix this when reading the dataset in.

Comment: @SabDem, I have tried that but it didn't work. I have tried with sum(as.numeric(as.factor(x)), na.rm = TRUE), sum(as.numeric(levels(x)[x]), sum(as.numeric(as.character(x)) and sum(as.numeric(levels(x))[x], na.rm = TRUE) but no hope.

Comment: @aosmith, I will check the data.

Comment: @aosmith, I have checked the data where there are not any null values. However there are some values such as 0.001 or 0.002, does that affect?

Comment: I've found that if R reads something numeric as a factor then it means I've put a character somewhere in my numeric column and I like to figure out where the problem is.  That being said, I can't guess why `sum(as.numeric(as.character(x)), na.rm = TRUE)` isn't working for you.

Comment: @aosmith, I found an error after the code was implemented. The new data table has some NA values. After analysing data visually, I found out that all the numbers greater than 999 such as 1,035.74, 5,650.09 are changed as NA values. Do you have any idea on how to keep those numbers.

Comment: See [this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594223/number-values-include-comma-how-do-i-make-these-numeric).

Comment: @aosmith, The code sum(as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))) works for me so I do not have to use as.character code. Thank you very much Aosmith.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `read.csv`, try setting the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. Or, you can make use of the argument `colClasses`, wherein you would do something like `read.csv("file.csv", colClasses=c("character", "integer","numeric"))` if the first column was a character, second an integer, and third column numeric.

Specifically, it sounds like you have a column that R is guessing is a "factor", so you should set that column to be "numeric" in `colClasses`.

That may save you some trouble converting things once they've been read into R.

Comment: Sorry to say that it doesn't give me the correct answer.